# Spurious space after math display in custom environment

Tags: spacing, environments

I created a very simple environment to display a text box inside an equation environment, so it gets an equation number (like an assertion).

When I use the environment, the following paragraph has a small extra space before the first character.  If I copy the environment code instead of using it, there is no problem.  Where is this extra space coming from?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}

\usepackage{lipsum, mathtools}

\newlength\claimlen
\setlength\claimlen{\textwidth-2cm}

\newenvironment{claim}
{% begin code
  \begin{equation}
  \begin{minipage}{\claimlen}
}%
{% end code
  \end{minipage}
  \end{equation}
}

\begin{document}

This is a test of a claim:
\begin{claim}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{claim}
And this is the line after, which is supposed to not be indented at all but as
you can see there is a small space at the beginning.

Now the same, but without the environment:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{minipage}{\claimlen}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{minipage}
\end{equation}
And this is the line after, which is supposed to not be indented at all and in
this case there is really no spurious space at the beginning.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Partial solution: remove the trailing space with `\end{claim}%`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding two spaces

```
  \end{equation}SPACE%
}
```

and

```
\end{claim}SPACE%
A
```

You need to not add the first and tell latex to ignore the second

End the definition

```
  \end{equation}% NO SPACE HERE
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know the \ignorespacesafterend command.